# Freexing an iFrame's content in the center

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, center, phpbb

I am trying to embed a phpBB forum into a wordpress page, but I cannot make the page any wider, and because there is a large blue area either side of the main content, most of the actual content is cut off. What i would like to do is center the content in the iFrame, then disble the sideways scrolling function. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you give us some accompanying HTML and CSS?  Even a screenshot could help.

Comment: Which phpBB template are you using? If its fixed width, try switching to a fluid layout (or changing your current template to fluid)

Comment: This is the forum. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1n845qalq06e74a/Screenshot%202014-05-27%2022.44.27.png . The iFrame always puts it off center, like this:https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngqb8wwfz4ke9j4/Screenshot%202014-05-27%2022.43.17.png , meaning the user has to center it in order to see the rest of the page. It is annoying. I would like to be able to center it like https://www.dropbox.com/s/4o6wmfakv2boody/Screenshot%202014-05-27%2022.45.26.png then disabe the ability to scroll the iFrame sideways